# Mail relay and php mail

Tags: php, email, sendmail, emailrelay

I have a VPS server at UltimateHosting.com and requires that I use "Smart Relay". I cant seem to wrap my head around how I setup php to be able to use mail relay.

Here is an article they have on Smart Relay:
http://support.ultrahosting.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=142

The server is using cpanel and exim

**I sent the following support ticket**:

> How do I configure the server to send
>   mail using php. I am writting a script
>   that will send the users passwsord
>   usigng PHPs mail function. However the
>   emails sent are never delivered. Does
>   this have to do with "smart relay"?
>   Any guide on how to configure this?

**Response was**:

> While we do not provide scripting
>   support of any kind, if you simply
>   ensure the smart host is hard coded in
>   your script (no authentication is
>   necessary) the email should be
>   forwarded accordingly.
>
> If your script uses the server's SMTP
>   server to send out email, you'll have
>   to ensure the MTA is configured to use
>   the smart host

.

Could anyone please clarify what I need to do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer on ServerFault see https://serverfault.com/questions/188840/configrue-exim-sendmail-for-relay for details.

In short, I needed to change the default generic hostname and apply the route relay